# How to change the button with a spinner in actionbar to loading?

Tags: java, android

I have a webview and want to listen its loading event and I have a refresh button on my actionbar.

How to change the button to a spinner programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can't magically change a button into a spinner.  What you **can** do is disable the button and enable the spinner.

```
myButton.setEnabled(false);
mySpinner.setEnabled(true);
```

If you want to make the spinner take the place of the button, then you're going to have to put all of your layout drawing routine into a buildLayout() (or whatever you want to call it) and redraw the entire layout with a button or with a spinner, depending on the state of your application.

Comment: how to make that spinner btw?